# console.log('hello',)

Tags: javascript, windows, консоль, браузер

Не знал как назвать, кто придумает по умнее, буду признателен.
Проблема в том, что **PhpStorm** не подчеркнул и я упустил из виду:

`console.log('hello',)`

Данная конструкция роняла сайт на **windows** машинах, когда на **mac** все работало.
Не знаю как искать, но как по спецификации, допускается ли такое?

По мне дак вполне нормально, вторая переменная **undefined**.

Comment: Ubuntu, Chrome: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: а по мне так какой-то бред) без обид, если уж вторая переменная `undefined` то ее хотя бы записать нужно в `console.log`

Comment: читабельность 0

Comment: @AlexKrass, оформите ответом пожалуйста, и ссылку было бы отлично, почитаю. Жаль что шторм и мак проигнорировали это. Я чуть с ума не сошел, когда трубка покраснела, а у меня все работает!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте откроем стандарт языка [ECMA-262 7-редакция от июня 2016](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Смотрим как вызываются у нас функции `12.3.4 Function Calls`.

Как видим при вызове функции ей передается объект `Arguments`. Который определяется следующим образом.

```
Arguments[Yield] :
  ( )
  ( ArgumentList[?Yield] )
```

То есть он может быть либо пустым, либо передаваться как `ArgumentList`.

```
ArgumentList :
  AssignmentExpression
  ArgumentList , AssignmentExpression
```

Как видим список состоит из значений `AssignmentExpression`, которые разделены запятыми. Тут начинается самое сложное в стандарте, так как `AssignmentExpression` это целая куча различных вариантов значений.

```
AssignmentExpression:
  ConditionalExpression
  YieldExpression
  ArrowFunction
  LeftHandSideExpression
  LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression

AssignmentOperator : one of 
  *= /= %= += ‐= <<= >>= >>>= &= ^= |= **=
```

То есть мы может указывать просто кучу всяких видов параметров: условные выражения, стрелочные функции, различные комбинации выражений, итераторы и многое другое. Но в общем-то нас интересует простейший вариант: `LeftHandSideExpression`.

```
LeftHandSideExpression:
  NewExpression
  CallExpression
```

Дальше идет целая вакханалия ссылок. Но в итоге все сводится либо к различным выражениям, либо в нашем случае к простейшим `IdentifierName` и `Identifier`. А они в свою очередь имеют такое определение:

```
IdentifierName ::
  IdentifierStart
  IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart ::
  UnicodeIDStart
  $
  _
  \ UnicodeEscapeSequenc
```

То есть в любом случае должны быть хотя бы одна буква Юникода и таким образом `AssignmentExpression` не может состоять из пустоты. Там обязательно должно идти хоть что-то, иначе было бы в стандарте `AssignmentExpression` помечен опционально (opt) для `ArgumentList`.

P.S. - И пусть потом кто-то попробует сказать, что стандарты это легко.

Comment: @Grundy, ты ли это?

Comment: @Aid, эээм... нет)) По крайней мере тому есть множество доказательств и нередко мы с ним пересекаемся в одном вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy, маскируешься, ясно дело, только он может выдержать боль чтения спецификации и не сойти с ума (ибо уже :))!